# Problemas con la petición Fetch

Tags: javascript, webservice, api, web, fetch

Tengo el siguiente cuerpo de código:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var raw = "{\n  \"deviceId\":\"IPTA-S-A000\"\n}";

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch('https://ekiavending.com:1880/leer_monedero', requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Pero al momento de ejecutar el `script` me sale el siguiente error:

> error TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.
>       at api.html:22

Answer (score 1):

Fíjate que en las opciones de tu request, si pones method GET no puedes poner body.

> body: Any body that you want to add to your request: this can be a
>   Blob, BufferSource, FormData, URLSearchParams, USVString, or
>   ReadableStream object. **Note that a request using the GET or HEAD
>   method cannot have a body.**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch.

Si tienes que pasarle parámetros tendrás que pasarlos en la URL:

`https://ekiavending.com:1880/leer_monedero?deviceId=IPTA-S-A000`

o utilizar otro método como POST.